# Programmatically setting checkboxes

Tags: angular

I am building out a user management screen in Angular 2 and I want to be able to manage the roles for a user from the screen. Currently, I have a list of all the roles (id and name) and a list of users which contains an array (id and name) of all the roles for that user. I want to be able to list the roles on the screen as checkboxes and be able to set them for the roles the user already has.

Currently I have all the roles listed in my template using *ngFor.

```
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-inline" style="display:inline" *ngFor="let role of allRoles">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                <span class="custom-control-description">{{role.name}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to populate the roles that have been selected. Should I have a list of all the roles for each user with a "selected" property, or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map your list of all roles into something that combines information from your user specific set of roles.

Assuming you have an `allRoles` collection in your component, you could do something like this:

```
this.usersService.getUserRoles(this.selectedUser.id)
  .subscribe(userRoles => {
        this.userRoles = this.allRoles.map(r => {
                return {
                    id: r.id,
                    name: r.name,
                    isAssigned: userRoles.some(ur => {
                      return ur.id == r.id;
                    })
                };
            });
        });
```

Essentially creating a list of all available roles, but simply marking the ones the user is assigned to.

**You can see a basic implementation with this Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/zCCwLko5Nf2W92Ac7q4i?p=preview

**Example using groups of roles:** https://plnkr.co/edit/OgAmFFozPMtQ75iOs5mR?p=preview

Comment: how would I do this if allRoles multi-dimensional? For instance i have an array of "role groups" and each item has an array of roles. do i need to add another loop?

Comment: @IsaacLevin - You can do a map inside a map to get a brand new collection that has all the info you want. Basically it's a nested loop.

Comment: @IsaacLevin - I've added an updated plunker showing how you might do this with groups of roles.

Answer (score 0):

Add `isChecked` **key** in your `roles` like(`isChecked: true/false`) and

Try something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [ngModel]="role.isChecked" (ngModelChange)="checkIfRoleSelected($event, role)">
```

here `checkIfRoleSelected()` for make changes in object for further use(API call).

Comment: I am not sure how that helps me... I basically have 2 lists, the list of all the roles, and a list of a user's roles. I need to be able to show the list of all roles with the user's roles checked.

Comment: Can you provide your data format? or see @Josh answer, will help you.